# What does the past participle function here?

Tags: relative-clauses, past-participles

> The purpose and meaning of the sand paintings can be explained by examining one of the most basic ideals of Navajo society, **embodied** in their word hozho (beauty or harmony, goodness, and happiness).(From TOEFL)

Is the past participle function as a shorten version of nonrestrictive relative clause? But I generally them as adverbial clause modifying the main verb of the sentence.

Comment: The text is examining an ideal (a standard towards which society should aspire), ***which is** embodied [made manifest, given metaphorically "physical" form] in/by that particular word **hozho***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is functioning as a non-finite clause, modifying the preceding noun phrase. Here, embodied is modifying "**one** of the most basic ideals of Navajo society".

It can be either restrictive or non-restrictive in general, but here the meaning is more restrictive since it is trying to specify "hozho" as the ideal that should be examined.

http://myenglishgrammar.com/lesson-17-clauses/6-finite-and-nonfinite-clauses.html

> But I generally them as adverbial clause modifying the main verb of the sentence.

An adverb clause needs a conjunction. Past participles can start an adverbial phrase, but even then it needs a noun phrase to attach to.

> Aided by the instructor, the student parked the car correctly.

The student was aided by the instructor.